# Remove all line that contain duplicate entry in column 2

Tags: awk

I have a large file of two columns, and I want to remove the line on the basis of duplicate entries in column 2. I want to delete both duplicate entries.

I tried:

```
awk '!seen[$2]++' filename
```

But it only deletes a single duplicate.

Input file example:

```
1  3
2  3
4  10
1  6
5  3
```

Expected output:

```
4  10
1  6
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{cnt[$2]++; next} cnt[$2]==1' file file
4  10
1  6
```

or if you can't read the input twice (e.g. if it's coming from a pipe) then:

```
$ awk '{rec[NR]=$0; key[NR]=$2; cnt[$2]++} END{for (i=1; i<=NR; i++) if (cnt[key[i]] == 1) print rec[i]}' file
4  10
1  6
```

Comment: Yes, it's printing in the same order as the input.

Answer (score 3):

Could you please try following.

```
awk '{seen[$2]++;value[$2]=$0} END{for(i in seen){if(seen[i]==1){print value[i]}}}' Input_file
```

Comment: Nice answer buddy!

Comment: That would print the input lines in "random" (probably hash) order. See https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Controlling-Array-Traversal

Answer (score 0):

With `coreutils` and `grep`:

```
# Sort on the second column
<infile sort -k2,2n | 

# Count number of repeated fields in the second column
uniq -f1 -c         | 

# Remove fields that are repeated
grep -E '^ +1 +'    | 

# Squeeze white-space
tr -s ' '           | 

# Remove repeat count
cut -d' ' -f3-
```

Output:

```
1 6
4 10
```

Answer (score 0):

Another with `sort`, `uniq` and `grep`:

```
$ grep -v -f <(sort -k2n file | uniq -f 1 -D) file
4  10
1  6
```

Explained: `sort` sorts the `file` on second field:

```
1  3
2  3
5  3
1  6
4  10
```

`uniq -f 1 -D` skips the first (*run of blanks* separated) field and prints only duplicated lines:

```
1  3
2  3
5  3
```

That list is an exclude list for `grep`.